# Downloading Windows 10 21H2 wrong build

Tags: windows

I'm trying to download Windows 10 21H2, which carries the build number 19044.

However, when I try to download Windows 10 via microsoft's website, it's downloading version 10.0.19041.1288, which is 20H1.

How can I download 19043 or higher?

Comment: Try the Microsoft Media Creation Link specifically and then use the first link in the page that comes up that says Upgrade to the newest Version or something like that.

Comment: @John I can't use that because we don't have a windows station with admin rights to run the tool.

Comment: To what end downloading the Windows update if you cannot install it. The only way a standard user’s machine can update is Automatic Updates with an overnight restart.

Comment: Its not the update Im trying to download its the OS itself.  Im transferring it to an airgapped computer that serves MDT.  So I need to download 21H2 instead of 20H1, full OS, not the update.

Comment: 'via microsoft's website' is a bit vague. Specifics may help. You should probably get the media creation tool & use that to load it to a USB stick.

Comment: You should be able to make a USB ISO  from the other link on the page I suggested you go to. Then take that update ISO and see if it can update the other machine. You might have to connect the other machine for a short time for driver updates.

Comment: @John @Tetsujin even after using the mediacreationtool for 21H2 I checked the build of the OS it downloaded with dism and it still shows as `10.0.19041`

Comment: Since your machine is not connected, you might wish to contact Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Windows 10 WIM images/ISOs. Multiple releases share the same operating system core. For example, I'm on 21H1 (19043) yet my `ntoskrnl.exe` still has version 19041.

Microsoft also has a [KB article on this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/version-and-build-number-are-reported-incorrectly-after-you-build-a-new-windows-image-file-0141c14e-b3b6-e4ab-88bb-6e3ba0d96b14). Unfortunately, it is somewhat out of date.

The "enablement packages" are:

- 20H2: Package_for_KB4562830
- 21H1: Package_for_KB5000736
- 21H2: Package_for_KB5003791 (indeed present in the image)

You can find links to these KB articles in the [release information page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information).

To check the packages, you have to mount the image in an (empty) folder:

```
dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:D:\sources\install.wim /index:1 /MountDir:C:\Path\To\Mount\Dir /ReadOnly
```

You can then use the following command to list the packages:

```
dism /Image:C:\Path\To\Mount\Dir /Get-Packages
```

After you're done, don't forget to unmount the image:

```
dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:C:\Path\To\Mount\Dir /discard
```